# How to get data from another collection by Extending Cloud Firestore with Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to send email onCreate as below

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import {sendEmail} from "./sendEmail";

// eslint-disable-next-line max-len
export const sendVerificationEmail = functions.firestore.document("/temporaryUsers/{id}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      const tempUserInfo = snapshot.data();
      const {
        userId,
        some,
      } = tempUserInfo;

...need email address from users collection...
  return sendEmail({
    to: <<emailAddress>>,
    from: "shaun.firebase.test1@gmail.com",
    subject: "My Reservation App Email Verification",
    message: `Cl......conf=${some}`,
  });
});
```

I tried

```
   const store = admin.firestore();
   const userInfoDoc = functions.firestore
       .collection("users")
       .doc(userId)
       .get();
```

and also

```
const userInfoDoc = firebase.firestore()
          .collection("users")
          .doc(userId)
          .get();

  const userInfo = userInfoDoc.data();
  const {email, firstName, lastName} = userInfo;
```

I am adding this import

> import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";

But I did not run any npm i (probably I have to...but that is the question)

> Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in
> the user code. Error message: Provided module can't be loaded. Did you
> list all required modules in the package.json dependencies? Detailed
> stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'firebase/compat/app' Require
> stack:

Is there a way to get user details using functions.firestore.document ? or any better way ?

Comment: When writing Firebase Cloud Functions with JavaScript, you should be using the Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js ([setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), [`firebase-admin` on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin), [API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin)).

Comment: Hi does my posted answer help ? If so then acknowledge it, if not then we can solve further.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get user details using functions.firestore.document ? or any better way ?

Yes as @samthecodingman mentioned above  use [**firebase-admin**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.firestore) to get the document from the firestore while using firebase functions.

Remove the import for `firebase/compat/app` as with this you are mixing the `firebase client` sdk with `firebase-admin`.

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
admin.initializeApp(); // Initializing Firebase admin SDK

const db = admin.firestore(); // Getting Firestore Instance

export const sendMail = functions.firestore
    .document("/temporaryUsers/{id}")
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
        const tempUserInfo = snapshot.data();
        const {
            userId,
            some
        } = tempUserInfo;
        console.log(tempUserInfo); //logging
        const snap = await db.collection("users").doc(userId).get(); //  Using Firebase Admin SDK
        const userInfo = snap.data();
        console.log(userInfo); // Retrieve email from this one
    });
```

Reference : [**Data outside the trigger event**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=1st#data_outside_the_trigger_event_2)

Comment: I do have admin.initializeApp(); in my index.js, I think I tried similar (not this yet), but is "await" allowed in the middle?? In my question , I already mentioned what models I tried. I will update after trying this

Comment: 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.

Comment: @KrisSwat Yes await can be used like this as we have made the trigger async